# My passport was lost at Kuala Lumpur airport. I reported at airport but my visa is expiring soon

Tags: indian-citizens, passports, lost-documents

I reported my missing passport 20 days ago. My visa is expiring in 10 days. What should I do?
How much money will the Indian embassy need for an emergency certificate ?

Comment: A Visa for what/where? Please [edit] your question. Did you check the website of the Indian embassy?

Comment: Yes I checked that but I have no money how much money will take at indian embassy

Comment: Please don't [post the same question twice](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/122974/11491). It just wastes everyone's time.

Answer (score 1):

Where did you report it? If you did not already apply for a new (emergency) passport, do that IMMEDIATELY. Then probably you should go to Malaysia’s immigration and explain the situation. You’ll have a hard time explaining why you waited so long before doing something about it, but better now then when you’re already overstaying.

Comment: At KL airport waiting for what they are say what should i do now how much money will take Indian embassy for a new passport